# Getting CREATE TABLE permission denied in database in EF6.1 while executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to fetch some records from a stored procedure in EF 6 using code first approach. Initially it was working as I was using 'sa' login for connection string. When I changed the login details in connection string it started throwing error

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database

For information I have disabled right on the database for accessing table. And so I am using stored procedures to access the data for all user excepts for sa user. I went into SQL Server profiler to see what actually the query is doing and saw its trying to create a table of my entity.

This is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<_BankHoliday_SP> _BankHoliday_SP
{
    get
    {
        var content = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<_BankHoliday_SP>("exec spConfigBankHolidayGet");
        return content;
    }
}
```

And when I try to access the data from the ViewModel class.

```
var bankHolidayList = _repository._BankHoliday_SP.ToList();
```

I am getting the error.

Comment: what are you doing in spConfigBankHolidayGet

Comment: I am simply doing Select query.

Comment: Weather is it executing from sql server

Comment: User in connection string used to access database has no create database right, so the exception is thrown. Try changing user or giving him access rights.

Comment: Did you consult [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx) page?

Answer (score 0):

try executing sp from sql server

> EXEC proc_name

if it works no need to pass exec with sp name

```
  var content = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<_BankHoliday_SP>("exec spConfigBankHolidayGet");
```

to

```
  var content = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<_BankHoliday_SP>("spConfigBankHolidayGet");
```